# why is this causing a memory leak

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, button

i am trying to launch a view from a button. When I do it causes a memory link but I can see why.

```
CamViewController *dvController = [[CamViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Cam_View" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
dvController.camType = 1; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES]; 
[dvController release];
```

any ideas?

Comment: What does your dealloc method look like?

Comment: This leaks happens after the Controller loads. i commented out all the code in the viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear functions just in case thats where the problem was. but no still have a memory leak for no good reason. i checked to see if i was releasing all IBOutlets and i am. so thats not the problem either.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most likely in your CamViewController implementation.  If I were to guess, you are creating a bunch of objects in your xib file and they are not getting released in the Controllers dealloc.

It is important to remember that you are responsible for releasing your IBOutlet attached objects in your class.

Comment: no thats not it. i double checked and yes im releasing all my IBOutlets and i am. the leak happens on the way TO the CamViewController.